# Android build path order

Tags: java, android, ant, build

I am using the android ant build for the first time. I have some libraries that override the libraries in the Android code. I can control the build order in Eclipse and everything works fine. When I build using the ant build, it appears to be importing the android libraries first before my overrides, which is causing compile errors because of missing constants, method names, etc.

Is there a way I can put my libraries ahead of the android ones so it will build correctly?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939757/ant-classpath-order) what you're looking for?

Comment: "I have some libraries that override the libraries in the Android code" -- that does not work, as you do not control the classpath at runtime, and so the libraries in the framework will supersede your duplicates, for any matches of fully-qualified class name.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't think that's true because we are already doing this with the deploy that runs from eclipse. We are simply trying to do the same thing with Ant.

Comment: @fifarunnerr The build.xml is part of android, so I can't directly modify the tasks. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: "I don't think that's true" -- yes, it is. One exception would be if you are deploying to your own custom build of Android, where you have modified these libraries in the OS. In that case, you should be building a custom SDK to go with that custom build, rather than fussing around with trying to change things at the classpath level.

Comment: @CommonsWare Aha! The libraries are custom for Motorola and we're deploying to Motorola devices, so the classpath on the phone is already set up correctly. All I need now is to get the build working.

Comment: And they didn't give you a custom SDK for this, or at least some instructions? That's disappointing. I'm not quite sure how you're going to address this, short of forking `build.xml` (and/or related files) and hacking 'em to modify the classpath. I don't even know a good way to do this in Gradle, though I haven't researched this point for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's a great idea! Thanks for that. Let me check the Motorola docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching (and the useless Motorola docs) I found a way to get my jars in front of android while still using the default build.xml file.

The android libraries come into the javac task as the bootclasspathref. This gets evaluated ahead of the standard jars, which is why I was having a problem.

Some research later, I see that compilerarg on the javac task is set to ${java.compilerargs}. I did some reading on the build.xml in my project that calls the default build.xml and it tells you how to override things in the default build.xml. So, at the end of the day, I changed three lines:

```
<!-- version-tag: custom -->
<!-- add the custom bluetooth libraries ahead of Android -->
<property name="java.compilerargs" value="-Xbootclasspath/p:/home/thomash/svn/air-android/branches/ticket_2198a/libs/BluetoothGatt.jar:/home/thomash/svn/air-android/branches/ticket_2198a/libs/BluetoothGattService.jar" />
```

The change to version-tag is important so android doesn't automatically destroy your changes on an upgrade.