# Same class in multiple jars. Jacoco Coverage

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I have Util.java class in two jars client.jar and server.jar. When i run integration test i don't get right coverage because two hash are generated for the same class. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: how do you define your dependencies please ? with maven ? in your IDE ?

Comment: Dependencies are defined in ant.

Comment: i think you can get your stuff here , it's a similar problem, who was fixed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939757/ant-classpath-order

Answer (score 0):

if i see it right, you want to have a server, which also work as a client with another server. Am I right?
You will have a main class or you call the client from out of the server. Create the class, which you want to use, in the main or in the server and then overhand it to both of them and led it share/handle between both of them.
if you have a client which should communicate with a server, you have to create the class in one of them and then send it via tcp/udp or whatever you use to the otherone

Comment: I agree with it. But my problem is bit complex. I have simplified things in my question, actually I'm working on a huge code base and there are around 703 classes which are getting duplicated. I can't change all this code because its a legacy code and i will break a lot of stuff.

Comment: ah ok, i didn't know this